# How do I set up a non .war based app in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I want to run something outside of Tomcat's ROOT web dir.
I used to do this in Tomcat 4, but can't seem to figure it out for the current version.

I'm pretty sure it's as easy as creating a folder that is a sibling to ROOT and in it's web.xml file identifying what the web path ought to be... but I just can't find the right syntax.

Does anyone have it handy?

much obliged if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

In short - you will have to define a `<Context>` element in your configuration, and specify a `docBase` pointing to your desired directory.